# How do you observe the width of an element in polymer?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, polymer

I was wondering how it is possible to observe changes to an element's css property such as the width.

I tried doing this but it didn't work. Where did I go wrong? Is it possible?

```
<polymer-element name="test-resize" attributes="elementWidth">
  <template>
    <p>elementWidth : {{elementWidth}}</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      elementWidth: 100,
      observe: {
        "clientWidth" : "updateWidth",
      },
      updateWidth: function(oldValue, newValue){
        this.elementWidth = newValue;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

In this example, I'm trying to observe the `clientWidth` property which you can normally access from outside.

Comment: Not recommended... https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js/issues/49

Comment: So...this is a really bad idea? I guess I'll figure out something else then because I don't feel like slowing my webpage down.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bad idea ;) Why did you want to observe the element's width? What process can make it change?

Comment: I made a [polymer element to swipe between pages](https://github.com/TheSeamau5/swipe-pages). Basically each individual page is inside this larger container, the element `<swipe-pages>`, and if this element gets resized, everything goes weird. So, I wanted to track the width of the container in order to resize everything accordingly and update all necessary properties to make the swiping work just fine.

Comment: The processes I considered would make it change are:
1) changing the width in css and/or javascript
2) resizing the screen
3) rotating the screen (mobile)

Comment: The best practice is generally to trap those explicit change signals. The `resize` event on `window` should fire because of (2) and (3), and changing the width programmatically is at least theoretically under your control (although I understand it can be a hassle to do it this way).

Comment: I'll think of something and continue to experiment. Thing is, I'd like my element to be really re-usable so I might not always have the control of the resizing but still would like it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a certain technique abusing CSS transitions and listening for the transitionend event. There are only a very few cases where it's really required (like if you want to adjust the resolution of a webgl context after the canvas dimensions changed in any way)

Add a transition in css to make the transition event fire when width/height change.

```
:host {
  transition:width 0.01s, height 0.01s;
}
```

Listen for the event and handle whatever you want to happen

```
this.addEventListener("transitionend",function(e){
  this.elementWidth = this.clientWidth;
})
```

[more info about implementing the technique, like polyfills you'll probably need](http://www.prevent-default.com/detect-size-change-of-elements-using-transitions/)

Comment: @TheSeamau5 sorry my bad. Shouldn't have made it look copy-pastable. Any problems in particular you have implementing it I can help you with?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it to work by following your link but in the end I found a way to do what I wanted without observing the width. It's a really odd trick though.