# Observe element style changes (height)

Tags: polymer

I would like to get notified any any change of the elements style changes (in my case: any change to the elements height).

I have tried to manually register an observer:

```
  observers: [
    'heightUpdated(style.height)',
  ],
```

This seems not to work (for any style properties).

I have also tried an other observer:

```
  observers: [
    'heightUpdated(clientHeight)',
  ],
```

This observer never gets called.

Comment: Depending on what kind of role your element has, using [`IronResizableBehavior`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-resizable-behavior?active=Polymer.IronResizableBehavior) might be just what you need

Comment: Thanks. The event seems not to be called when the element size gets changed via CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692678/how-do-you-observe-the-width-of-an-element-in-polymer

Answer (score 2):

The only way i've found to observer changes to style properties of a Polymer element, is to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

It can easily be set up to listen for any change to any of the .style. properties such as .style.height, but it has a lot of restrictions.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/cijivu/edit?js) is one I set up earlier

```
Polymer({
  is: "my-element",
  properties: {

    // Saved to the element, so you can inspect it if you want
    mutationObserver: {
      value: function() {

        // uses the function "mutated" defined later"
        var observer = new MutationObserver(this.mutated.bind(this));
        observer.observe(this, { 

          // Only fires on attribute changes
          attributes: true, 
          attributeOldValue: true,

          // Only fires when the "style" attribute changes
          attributeFilter : ['style'],
        });
        return observer;
      },
    },
    height: String,
  },
  observers: [
    'heightUpdated(height)'
  ],
  mutated: function(mutations) {
    // Change this function if you want to listen for something else instead, this is fired on all "style" changes, and you can see the changes inside the "mutations" object it provides
    this.set('height', this.style.height);  
  },
  heightUpdated: function(height) {
    console.log('height', height);
  }
});
```

It listens whenever this.style.height is set, but not when you resize the element.

Hopefully, the mutation observer will be updated with a [css extension](http://xml3d.org/xml3d/specification/styleobserver/) to provide better support for listening to css style changes. Until then I don't think this is the best option I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I need to get notified when the element gets resized via CSS which seems not to work with this code.

Comment: Yes, it won't be notified of changes to stylesheets, only inline css. The css extension as the end of my answer, which is currently only a draft seems to be the only way to do this, other than polling. If it ever becomes a reality i'll update my answer, until then I think this is the best there is. I'll also put polling into my answer if you want, but it's no where near as good as observing.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Polling is not a "real" solution IMHO. I've voted this answer +1, but not accepted since it does not resolve my issue. Thanks.